# ResponsiveNess using BootStrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using below HTML with bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
<div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8</div>
</div>
```

I would like to keep them side by side when the screen is less than 576px wide. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the classes `col-4` and `col-8` instead of `col-sm-4/8`. This way, this grid will apply to every type of screen instead of being above the threshold of sm.

[here you can read more about Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)